# How can I override the drag event for jQuery ui sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

On the jQuery UI site, it says that "By default, sortable items share draggable properties." I assumed this meant that all events that draggable has, sortable should inherit as well. However, this doesn't seem to be the case. I need something like the "drag" event in draggable for a sortable grid so that I can manually update the x and y values of an element that's being dragged. So far, I've been able to get the X and Y values of the dragged element using the mousemove event and some flags, but I can't get it so that the X and Y values can be set. When I try to set the values, they simply get reset by the next time the event is fired (it probably happens just after the mousemove event). Does anybody know of a way to accomplish this?

Here is a fiddle for what I've tried so far: http://jsfiddle.net/turtlewaxer1100/CUXxn/5/

**HTML**

```
<div class="row grid span8">
    <div class="well span2 tile">A</div>
    <div class="well span2 tile">B</div>
    <div class="well span2 tile">C</div>
    <div class="well span4 tile">D</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.placeholder {
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888;
}
.tile {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.grid {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

**JS**

```
var dragging = false;

$(function () {
    $(".grid").sortable({
        start: dragging = function(e, ui) {
          return dragging = true;
        },
        stop: dragging = function(e, ui) {
          return dragging = false;
        },
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        revert: 'invalid',
        placeholder: 'span2 well placeholder tile',
        forceHelperSize: true,

        // Drag doesn't work as an event in sortable.
        drag: function() 
        {
            console.log("Drag fired!");
        }
    });

    // My attempt at a custom drag event. (can get values, but can't set them.)
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        if(dragging===true)
        {
            // Grab the sortable element being moved. 
            element = $(".ui-sortable-helper");

            // Show the current X and Y values. (get reset after manually setting them below)
            console.log("before: X: " + element.css("left") + ", Y: " + element.css("top"));   

            // Change the X and Y values to something arbitrary.
            element.css("left",0);
            element.css("top",0);

            // Show the X and Y values after the change. 
            console.log("after: X: " + element.css("left") + ", Y: " + element.css("top")); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the [sort](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-sort) event of the sortable.

```
 sort: function(event, ui) 
        {
            console.log("Drag fired!");
            ui.helper.css("left",0);
            ui.helper.css("top",0);
        }
```

Here is your updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CUXxn/6/)

Comment: Awesome! This does exactly what I needed. I wonder why they don't call that event drag... it seems like that's exactly what it is. Thanks.

Comment: ahh because it actually sorts the element by dragging them around. so basically its a sort ;)